# Problem with importing some .models from the 2 folders in one bigger one

Tags: python, django

I moved my django project from Atom to PyCharm and there is a problem, when i wrote,

```
from .models import BookItem
```

I get an error.

I tried to fix that with double dot, with adding full path, but it still does not work, does anyone know what I can do?

I tried

```
 from shelf.models import BookItem
 from ..models import BookItem
```

even

```
from wypozycz.shelf.models import BookItem
```

The error I receive is:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'BookItem' from 'rental.models'

Comment: how is your project structured ?

Comment: It looks like:<br>
'Django Project  

''''wypozycz
''''''''contact
''''''''''''''''allfiles like admin.py/models.py
''''''''rental 
''''''''''''''''all files like admin.py/models.py
'''''''' shelf
''''''''''''''''all files like admin.py/models.py 
''''''''wypozycz
''''''''''''''''all files like admin.py/models.py

And i would like to move that BookItem from shelf to rental